# React Jest test error when using Capitalized name in import

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, jsx

Jest version: 16.0.1

Can someone please tell me why this Jest test throws an error when I change the import name from `myComp` to `MyComp`

Home.test.js

```jsx
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Home } from './Home.js';
import React from 'react';

describe('Link', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
      <Home />
    );
    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Home.js

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { default as myComp } from './MyComp';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export function Home() {
  return (
    <View>
      <myComp />
    </View>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

MyComp.js

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

class MyComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>hello there</Text>
    );
  }
}

MyComp.propTypes = {};

export default connect()(MyComp);
```

The error I get when I change `Home.js`'s import `... default as myComp...` to `...default as MyComp`

*Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(MyComp)". Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(MyComp)".*

Comment: Wow I'm receiving this error too, and also currently on Jest 16.0.1... Not sure why this is happening, but I had to change the name of my class to lowercase for my Jest test to work.

Comment: Actually, I was able to revert the class name to upper case e.g. `class MyComp extends React.Component { ... }` and then in my test, I `import { myComp } from '../MyComp'` instead of doing `import { MyComp } from '../MyComp'`